# Playing audio in Xcode 7 / Swift 2 Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, swift2, xcode7

I am currently on Xcode 7 beta 4 with Swift 2, trying to play audio. I do not get any error in my code, but when I press the play button, the audio does not play. I cant figure out what is wrong.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VesuviusViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var PausePlay: UIButton!

    func playVes() {
        do {

        _ = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ves", ofType: "m4a")!))

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        playVes()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }
}
```

***UPDATE***
Correct code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VesuviusViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var PausePlay: UIButton!



@IBAction func playPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    VesSet()
}
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    func VesSet(){


        do {
            self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ves", ofType: "m4a")!))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }


    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer! // Global variable
```

And play method:

```
func playVes() {
        do {
            self.audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ves", ofType: "m4a")!))
            self.audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have been trying to solve this for days. Many answers later...This finally worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AshishKakkad you forgot the self

Comment: This actually works on iOS 9.3 and Swift 2.1, unlike most other solutions...:) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Current code working as of xCode 7.0 Swift 2.0
Still working as of October 9, 2015

```
//Declaration
var hitSoundPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

//Added into the didMoveToView(view: SKView) Function
do {
    hitSoundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: hitSound)
        hitSoundPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
} catch _ {
        hitSoundPlayer = nil
}

//When you want to play it
hitSoundPlayer!.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happening to you but there are multiple ways of implementing sound into your project. Try this way:

```
class Hello : UIViewController {

  var Audio1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mySound", ofType: "wav")!)
  var AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {

  AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: Audio1, error: nil)
}

func playsound() {

  AudioPlayer.play()

}
```