# Error 849 in livestreaming application on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, http-live-streaming

I am working on the livestream feature for an iOS application. I have used an AVPlayerViewController contained within a ContainerView to display the video.

[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

And here is the associated code for the ViewController

```obj-c
@interface ViewController ()

@property MPMoviePlayerController* streamPlayer;
@property BOOL isPlaying;

@end

AVPlayerViewController *streamPlayer;

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.isPlaying = NO;

NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/appleman.m3u8"];

streamPlayer = [[ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StreamPlayer" ];


streamPlayer.player = [ AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamURL ];

}

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender{


    if ( !self.isPlaying ){

    [ streamPlayer.player play ];

    [self.button setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

        self.isPlaying = YES;
    } else {

        [ streamPlayer.player pause ];

        [self.button setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

        self.isPlaying = NO;
    }

}
```

*(You can ignore the isPlaying variable. It's just to see what I can control)*

The stream starts and works fine for a few minutes before it stops/buffers(i think) for a few seconds and an error show up:

```obj-c
ERROR: 849: AudioQueue: request to trim 4291961269 + 0 = 4291961269 frames from buffer containing 21504 frames
```

The stream continues after this but there is no audio.

Occasionally there is a second or two of audio but immediately the error showing up again and the stream continues in silence. (Something I'm glad of when a Pitbull video is being broadcast. )

If I pause the stream and then play it, the audio returns for a few minutes and then goes off again.

I have searched for this error but have not found anything to help me fix this. Being relatively new to iOS and HLS, I don't have any ideas as to what the issue could be but if I had to guess I'd say that it's an issue with synchronization of audio and video.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues in your code that stand out right away.

1. You have TWO `streamPlayer` variables.
2. The `AVPlayerViewController` variable should be a *Global Variable*

By putting your `AVPlayerViewController` property declaration inside your Interface Extension as a **global variable** the error should be resolved.

The code would look something like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *mpStreamPlayer;
@property (nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *avStreamPlayer;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPlaying;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad ... // continue as expected
```

The reason I am assuming it will be resolved is because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715341/playing-audio-in-xcode-7-swift-2-not-working) similar problem a member of the community is experiencing with the **Error 849** (their codebase is SWIFT) and the answer working answer.

Answer (score 2):

this is possibly related to the iOS 9 bugs, paste your m3u8 into the Safari, you could experience the same problem down the road (intermediate audio interrupt, audio/video out of sync), there is nothing you can do with your code.

see some report [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19017), and Apple engineer ask to file a bug report.